# How to inclusion a file to index.html with feathers.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fs, feathersjs

I'm learning a feathers and I have a problem. I try to do file inclusion similar to switch of PHP.

For example:

/src/middleware/index.js

```
'use strict';

const handler = require('feathers-errors/handler');
const notFound = require('./not-found-handler');
const logger = require('./logger');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const fs = require('fs');

const path = require('path')
const filename = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public')

module.exports = function() {
  // Add your custom middleware here. Remember, that
  // just like Express the order matters, so error
  // handling middleware should go last.

const app = this;

app.get('/record.html', function(req, res) {

  var html = fs.readFileSync(filename + '/index.html');
  var home = fs.readFileSync(filename + '/record.html');
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  $('#content').html(home);
  res.send($.html());
});

  app.use(notFound());
  app.use(logger(app));
  app.use(handler());
};
```

I corrected my file. I made sure that I'm doing as you write, and unfortunately I have a problem. When I open http://127.0.0.1:3030/record.html I'm getting only record.html without mixed files. If I change path from record.html on records.html e.g.

```
app.get('/records.html', function(req, res) {

  var html = fs.readFileSync(filename + '/index.html');
  var home = fs.readFileSync(filename + '/record.html');
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  $('#content').html(home);
  res.send($.html());
});
```

In this way is OK but I want to have original path in URL. An URL must to have path like file name.
In turn, if I add :file instead records.html in case, if the file does not exist I getting error "Oh no!" instead 404.

for example:

```
app.get('/:file.html', function(req, res) {

  var file = req.params.file

  var html = fs.readFileSync(filename + '/index.html');
  var home = fs.readFileSync(filename + '/' + file + '.html');
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  $('#content').html(home);
  res.send($.html());
});
```

And yet one question.

```
const path = require('path')
const filename = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public')
```

If in app.js file is const path, I have to put above code in each file like middleware or service when I want to serve file from public directory? I can not use a global variable for all files in this app?

app.js

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');                          <-- HERE const path
const serveStatic = require('feathers').static;
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const compress = require('compression');
const cors = require('cors');
const feathers = require('feathers');
const configuration = require('feathers-configuration');
const hooks = require('feathers-hooks');
const rest = require('feathers-rest');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const socketio = require('feathers-socketio');
const middleware = require('./middleware');
const services = require('./services');

const app = feathers();

app.configure(configuration(path.join(__dirname, '..')));

app.use(compress())
  .options('*', cors())
  .use(cors())
  .use(favicon( path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico') ))
  .use('/', serveStatic( app.get('public') ))
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(rest())
  .configure(socketio())
  .configure(services)
  .configure(middleware);

module.exports = app;
```

1) How can I show page with mixed file with the path of file name e.g. http://127.0.0.1:3030/record.html

2) If I use :file in app.get() how to show error 404 when a file not exists?

3) Do I have to use const path in each file wherein I want to serve a file or mixed files?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason that wouldn't work in Feathers but in a generated application you have make sure that - just like in Express - you include your middleware *before* the error handler (e.g. in `middleware/index.js` [here](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/master/src/middleware/index.js#L17) otherwise you will always get a 404.

Comment: I have yet one question. If I added app.get() into index.js in /src/middleware, how can I inclusion a file from /public directory?

Comment: In that file with `const path = require('path')` and `const filename = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public', 'index.html')`